# Sentence Alignment with thesis title (LaTex)

Tags: latex, indentation

I am new in Latex. I am having trouble aligning committee member part with the Title part. I tried but could not solve it. Could you please help me out.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in]{geometry}% change margin size
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{setspace} % for double spacing pakage

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{0cm} % moving title a little lower
\doublespacing
{\textsc{Growth and Characterization of  and  doped $\beta-Ga_{2}O_{3}$ }}\\
by\\
XXXX  Mia
%\Large{\textbf{Internal Assessment}}\\
\vfill % vertical spacing maker automatically
\end{center}

\begin{center}
A dissertation submitted to the Graduate Council of\\
XXXX  University in partial fulfillment\\
of the requirements for the degree of\\ Doctor of Philosophy\\
with a Major in Material Science, Engineering  and Commercialization\\
\today

\end{center}
\vfill
\doublespacing
Committee Members: \\
\indent Prof. xx, Chair\\
\indent  Larson \\
\indent  Hanks \\
\indent Wilhelmus  \\
\indent  Chen\\


%\indent $ \today$

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

TeX works by defining boxes. These boxes contain any visible material: character, images, other boxes, etc. And the task of the typesetting software is to place these boxes on the page according to the analysis of the content (to add line breaks) or to directives given by the user.

So what you want is:
1. turn the committee list into a box
2. position this box somewhere on the line

The first task is done by the  `minipage` environment. This environment has one mandatory argument, the width of the minipage and several optional arguments that are not relevant here. Minipages are one of the most useful latex feature to finely control typesetting.

Task 2 is done by adding *glue* (space) around the box. I have used `\hspace{len}` to add a fixed length space, but other commands may be useful according to what you want: `\hfill` to push the box to the  right side of the page, `\begin{center}...\end{enter}` to center the box,etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in]{geometry}% change margin size
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{setspace} % for double spacing pakage

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{0cm} % moving title a little lower
\doublespacing
{\textsc{Growth and Characterization of  and  doped $\beta-Ga_{2}O_{3}$ }}\\
by\\
XXXX  Mia
%\Large{\textbf{Internal Assessment}}\\
\vfill % vertical spacing maker automatically
\end{center}

\begin{center}
A dissertation submitted to the Graduate Council of\\
XXXX  University in partial fulfillment\\
of the requirements for the degree of\\ Doctor of Philosophy\\
with a Major in Material Science, Engineering  and Commercialization\\
\today

\end{center}
\vfill
\hspace{10cm}%
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
\doublespacing
Committee Members: \\
\indent Prof. xx, Chair\\
\indent  Larson \\
\indent  Hanks \\
\indent Wilhelmus  \\
\indent  Chen\\
\end{minipage}

%\indent $ \today$

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]